# Deploying to Cloud Run with a custom service account failed with iam.serviceaccounts.actAs error

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-run, google-iam

I have created a custom service account `travisci-deployer@PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com` on my project and gave it the **Cloud Run Admin** role:

```sh
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding "${PROJECT_ID}" \
   --member="serviceAccount:${SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL}" \
   --role="roles/run.admin"
```

Then I set this service account as the identity for my gcloud commands:

```sh
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=google-key.json
```

But when I ran `gcloud beta run deploy` command, I got an error about the "Compute Engine default service account" not having `iam.serviceAccounts.actAs` permission:

```sh
gcloud beta run deploy -q "${SERVICE_NAME}" \
  --image="${CONTAINER_IMAGE}" \
  --allow-unauthenticated
```

```
Deploying container to Cloud Run service [$APP_NAME] in project [$PROJECT_ID] region [us-central1]
Deploying...
Deployment failed
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.run.deploy) PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission 'iam.serviceaccounts.actAs'
denied on service account 1075231960084-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
```

This seems weird to me (because I'm not using the GCE default service account identity, although it's used by Cloud Run app once the app is deployed).

So the `1075231960084-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com` account is being used for the API call, and not my `travisci-deployer@PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceacount` service account configured on `gcloud`?

How can I address this?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

**TLDR: Add *Cloud Run Admin* and *Service Account User* roles to your service account**.

If we read the docs in detail for the IAM Reference page for Cloud Run which is found [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/iam/roles#additional-configuration), we find the following text:

> A user needs the following permissions to deploy new Cloud Run
> services or revisions:
>
> - `run.services.create` and `run.services.update` on the project level.
>   Typically assigned through the `roles/run.admin` role. It can be changed
>   in the project permissions admin page.
> - `iam.serviceAccounts.actAs` for
>   the Cloud Run runtime service account. By default, this is
>   `PROJECT_NUMBER-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`. The permission
>   is typically assigned through the `roles/iam.serviceAccountUser` role.

I think these extra steps explain the story as you see it.

Comment: In particular, if `roles/iam.serviceAccountUser` were not checked, it would be possible for a user with either of the `run.*` permissions to do anything that the service account running the service can do (by holding code to do the thing for them, possibly including starting a compute VM with known login credentials). Requiring permission to `actAs` the service account for the Service closes this loophole by making the required permission explicit.

Comment: This makes sense now, thanks! I was looking at deploying to GAE with Travis CI tutorial https://cloud.google.com/solutions/continuous-delivery-with-travis-ci and couldn't see something similar to this, which got me confused.

Comment: FYI: Having the role `Cloud Run Admin` is not enough to deploy, you'll need to also have the role `Cloud Run Service Agent` as well.

Comment: What I regret with GCP, in particular in IAM, is that the technical name of the privilege in question is not directly searchable in the list when adding a role. How can you quickly figure out that `iam.serviceAccounts.actAs` is equivalent to *Service Account User*?  If you quickly type "service accounts" in the textarea, it won't come up... because it's plural.... The search engine should allow both technical name and human name.

Comment: @FabienHaddadi go to `IAM & Admin -> Roles -> filter box -> enter permission (iam.serviceAccounts.actAs)`. You'll see the number of roles go down drastically (eg from 1500 to 30). If you still have many (like 30!), you can add filters, eg add `Title:run` to filter on just the cloud run related roles that have that permission.

Answer (score 15):

Adding **Cloud Run Admin** and **Service Account User** roles to my own service account fixed this for me. See step 2 in the docs here:
https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/continuous-deployment#continuous

Comment: This is literally what the answer accepted above says.

Comment: You are right, but I found it much easier to follow the instructions provided in the link in my answer (and maybe also for anyone else not so familiar with configuring IAM permissions).

Comment: @ahmet, no it isn't. This gives a link to explicit steps, instead of a general explanation. Both are useful, but not the same.

Answer (score 2):

For the best practice, you should only allow specific permission for the cloud run instance.

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/iam/roles#additional-configuration

Assuming you have two service accounts in your GCP.

One is the Clound Run `identity service account/runtime service account`.

Let it as `identity-cloudrun@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com` and this service account doesn't need to assign any permission to it because it is just as a identiy for the cloud run. If you need this cloud run instance access other GCP resource, you may add some permission for this service account.

Another one is the `Deployment Service account` which is used to deploy your Cloud Run.

Let it as `deploy-cloudrun@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

For the `Deployment Service account`, you need to grant `Cloud Run Admin permissions` to it specific to `your-cloudrun-instance`. So, it cannot access other cloud run instance.

```
gcloud run services add-iam-policy-binding your-cloudrun-instance \
--member="serviceAccount:deploy-cloudrun@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
--role="roles/run.admin" \
--region=europe-west1
```

Also, you need to grant `iam.serviceAccounts.actAs` permission of `identity service account` to your `deployment service account`. This is mentioned by the documentation.

```bash
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding \
identity-cloudrun@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
--member="serviceAccount:deploy-cloudrun@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
--role="roles/iam.serviceAccountUser"
```

So, you can deploy your cloud run like below by your `deployment service account`.

**Note: In practice, you should use [workload identity federation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/workload-identity-federation) instead using your `deployment service account` directly.**

```
gcloud run deploy your-cloudrun-instance \
--image="us-docker.pkg.dev/cloudrun/container/hello" \
--service-account="identity-cloudrun@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
```

Answer (score -2):

Though you can resolve this particular error by granting the account permission to act as the Compute Engine default service account, it goes against the ["best practices" advice](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/service-accounts):

> By default, Cloud Run services run as the default Compute Engine service account. However, Google recommends using a user-managed service account with the most minimal set of permissions. Learn how to deploy Cloud Run services with user-managed service accounts in the Cloud Run service identity documentation.

You can indicate which service account identity the Cloud Run deployment will assume like so:

```sh
gcloud run deploy -q "${SERVICE_NAME}" \
  --image="${CONTAINER_IMAGE}" \
  --allow-unauthenticated \
  --service-account "${SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL}"
```

Answer (score -4):

Currently, in beta, all Cloud Run services run as the default compute account (The same as the Google Compute Engine default service account).

The ability to run services as a different service account will be available in a future release.